# Is there a way to detect when a DOM node is about to be removed from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web

Is there a way to detect when a DOM node is about to be removed from the DOM? ie. something like `onBeforeNodeRemoved`?

I am currently using mutation observers and the node appears to have already been removed by this point.

**Edit:** The use-case is that an AngularJS 1.x application is being removed from the DOM by AngularJS-unaware code, and I want to detect the DOM node removal and invoke `rootScope.$destroy`.

Comment: You can wrap your removing function and call custom event. I think you remove elements by jQuery remove - so, wrap that one, or extend htmldomelement prototype.

Comment: What's the use case? If you explain what you're trying to do, there may be alternative methods.

Comment: Amended question.

Comment: Maybe with MutationObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, it sounds like you're saying that by the time you get your mutation observers in place, the node you are trying to watch is already removed. So you never manage to observe it.

If this is the case get your mutation observers into the page and setup before anything else at all. It's the only way I can see that you would be able to observe "everything" that happens.